# Are canvas elements created via raphael.js cached?

Tags: javascript, canvas, raphael

I am would like vectorize a multicolor logo on a website. 
If it was monchromatic, I would use icomoon.io and a custom icon font. 
As it's not, I could draw it via raphael.js

But I wouldn't want the logo to have to be drawn anew on each page load.
So is the created canvas cached?

Or can caching be achieved in any way?

Comment: you could use ajax, and only change the part of your site thats different. To make it easier, look for jQuery and $.ajax

Comment: Joris, what you propose means trading one small problem for 1000 big ones.

Comment: yes, that's true. But when you are used to it, it will make you're webdevelloping a lot interresing ;) and you don't need to rerender the hole site, so it's by far the fastes way to open different webpages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Raphael will not cache your canvas between page requests. The logo will need to be drawn anew each time the page loads but, depending on how complicated it is, it shouldn't take very long at all.

You could consider exporting with [Raphael.Export](https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.Export) and saving the resultant SVG string in `localStorage` or something, but this will only work on newer browsers, and will still require loading via javascript.

EDIT: I mentioned just using an image, but you said you want to vectorise, doh!

Comment: I just would like the logo to be sharp on all devices. It's not that complicated, but still... can you recommend a best practice for embedding vector graphics? Maybe via native SVG and using raphael only as fallback?

Comment: I believe there a couple of libraries that will allow SVG to render in older versions of IE, [SVGweb](https://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) seemed like the strongest candidate when I was faced with a similar problem. That would allow you to just use an SVG file, which could then be cached.

Comment: SVGweb is also recommended by http://html5please.com/#polyfill so yes, sounds good

Comment: BUT I now realize there's a simpler solution! I'll place the logo via SVG and use a PNG as fallback (detecting via modernizr) :-)

Comment: That is better, as long as you don't have to support IE6 (with its PNG transparency issues)